# JQuery HoverIntent Returning Null

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

For my application, I use the hover intent add-on for mouse over/out panels.  This extension works on every page of my application except for one, and unfortunately the problem only happens in production and not development.

In this one page, the problem that occurs is that hoverIntent is not a function.  Again, this works in all of the other pages, but not this one.

I put a breakpoint in where the script adds on the plugin, and I test that jQuery.fn.hoverIntent and $(this).hoverIntent is a valid method (and it is).  But soon as the page runs to where my code that uses the hoverIntent method, it is undefined...

I'm not sure where to start.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue; it was related to a duplicate JQuery script reference for that one page.

Answer (score 0):

Try locating it inside the `$(document).ready()`

Else, the fact that other pages work fine, you need to figure out what is different about that page, its possible that page is calling some other javascript that is overriding or altering your methods.

Comment: It's standard script where the error happens, so that's weird.  And it works in other environments...  Very strange.